# cakephp create a session variable which is accassable on the different prefixed url

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to define a session variable like:

Created in Controllers/UsersController.php:

```
`$session->write('logout_url',$logout_url);`
```

The issue is that this is not avaliable on different prefixed url, only at the same prefixed url:

- cakeproject.com/users/profile // avaliable the session variable
- cakeproject.com/admin/users/profile //session variable is not
  avaliable

I have the following settings in the config/routes.php

```
   $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'profile', 'home']);

   $routes->connect('/admin', ['prefix'=>'admin','controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'home']);
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Does your admin routing go through a different setup somehow? There are obvious reasons why a cookie (and hence the session it references) accessible to `cakeproject.com` might not be available to `admin.cakeobject.com`, but much less so for one path vs another.

Comment: thank you @GregSchmidt for your help. I added my routes settings to the question

Comment: I'm confused. I'm not an expert on Cake routing, but that seems to map just the `/` and `/admin` URLs. What are `/users/profile` and `/admin/users/profile` (referenced in your original question) meant to do?

Comment: @GregSchmidt /users/profile means users controller and profile view, while /admin/users/profile : admin subdirectory's users controller, admin subdirectory's profile view

Comment: Do you have other settings in your routes file than what you've shown? My understanding is that the second one you have there would map exactly the `/admin` URL, but not `/admin/users/profile`. Other examples of this sort of thing that I've seen have always been quite different.